# connect javascript with html (a href)

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, hyperlink, geomap

I'm visualizing data with d3 javascript. I want to show in a geomap where I have been and when I was there. For that I have a timeline of one year. When I was in "Berlin" on March the timeline shows "March" and Berlin is highlighted on the map.

Now I want to connect this visualization with a blog entry.

For example I want to say: I was in "Berlin". When I click on "Berlin", I want to be send to the visualization via 
Berlin. In the map I want the timeline to be on "March" and "Berlin" to be highlighted.
Is this possible?

Is it possible to give parameters to the html-code, to be used in the javascript-section?

Comment: yes it is possible, thousand ways to rome

Answer (score 1):

You can use many attributes as a means to hold dynamic data in html elements. Example html:

```
<div id="berlin" class="city-wrapper" blog-link="march">BERLIN CONTENT</div>
```

And javascript:

```
var city = document.getElementById("berlin");
city.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var blogLink = this.getAttributeNode("blog-link").value;
    updateTimeline(blogLink); //Function to update the timeline according to element id
});
```